# where are the #list looped variables in Netbeans wizard freemarker

Tags: java, netbeans, freemarker

I'm using netbeans freemarker to generate JSF pages from Entity classes.
in list.ftl file I have

```
 <#list entityDescriptors as entityDescriptor>
                        <#if entityDescriptor.id != "id" && entityDescriptor.id != "version">
                        <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-6 ui-lg-4">
                                <p:outputLabel styleClass="template-labels" 
                                    value="${r"#{"}${bundle}.${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}${r"}"}" for="@next" />
                            <#if entityDescriptor.dateTimeFormat?? && entityDescriptor.dateTimeFormat != "">
                            <p:inputMask mask="9999/99/99" id="${entityName}_editForm_${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}" value="${r"#{"}${managedBean}.selected${entityName}.${entityDescriptor.name?replace("item.","")}${r"}"}" 
                                         converter="JalaliDateConverter" onfocus="serp.showDatePicker(this)" styleClass="PersianDate template-fields" title="${r"#{"}${bundle}.${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}${r"}"}"
                                         disabled="${r"#{"}!${managedBean}.${entityName?uncap_first}Editable${r"}"}"/>
                            <#elseif entityDescriptor.returnType?matches(".*[Bb]+oolean")>
                            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="template-fields" id="${entityName}_editForm_${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}" 
                                                     value="${r"#{"}${managedBean}.selected${entityName}.${entityDescriptor.name?replace("item.","")}${r"}"}"
                                                     disabled="${r"#{"}!${managedBean}.${entityName?uncap_first}Editable${r"}"}"/>
                            <#elseif entityDescriptor.blob>
                            <p:inputTextarea styleClass="template-fields" id="${entityName}_editForm_textArea" rows="4" cols="30" id="${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}" 
                                             value="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.name}${r"}"}" title="${r"#{"}${bundle}.${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}${r"}"}"
                                             disabled="${r"#{"}!${managedBean}.${entityName?uncap_first}Editable${r"}"}"/>
                            <#elseif entityDescriptor.relationshipOne>
                            <p:selectOneMenu styleClass="template-fields" id="${entityName}_editForm_${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}" value="${r"#{"}${managedBean}.selected${entityName}.${entityDescriptor.name?replace("item.","")}${r"}"}"
                                             disabled="${r"#{"}!${managedBean}.${entityName?uncap_first}Editable${r"}"}">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="${r"#{"}${bundle}.SelectOneMessage${r"}"}"/>
                                <f:selectItems value="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.valuesGetter}${r"}"}" var="${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}Item" itemValue="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}Item${r"}"}" itemLabel="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}Item.name${r"}"}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                            <#elseif entityDescriptor.relationshipMany>
                            <p:selectManyMenu styleClass="template-fields" id="${entityName}_editForm_${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}" value="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.name}${r"}"}"
                                              disabled="${r"#{"}!${managedBean}.${entityName?uncap_first}Editable${r"}"}">
                                <f:selectItems value="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.valuesGetter}${r"}"}" var="${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}Item" itemValue="${r"#{"}${entityDescriptor.id?replace(".","_")}Item${r"}"}"/>
                            </p:selectManyMenu>
                        <#elseif entityDescriptor.id != "id" && entityDescriptor.id != "version">
</#list>
```

`entityDescriptor` has fields like `entityDescriptor.blob` or `entityDescriptor.relationshipOne`, where can I find these possible variables like blob, id, valuesGetter or relationshipOne?
I've checked the freemarker.jar source and their website documentation but it seems it's more likely related to netbeans wizard.

ps: I'm looking to find a ManyToMany condition and asked it before which was vague or misleading anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the implementation details of the data-model, but generally if you can do `entityDescriptor.blob`, then `entityDescriptor?keys` should give a list that contains `"blob"` among others. The idea to grasp is that in FTL `entityDescriptor.blob` and `entityDescriptor["blob"]` are exactly the same, so `entityDescriptor` is kind of like `Map` with `String` keys (even if it's not necessarily a `Map`, FTL sees it similarly to that). Hence, you can even list the key-value pairs as `<#list entityDescriptor as k, v>`, as you would naturally expect from a `Map`-like object.

Comment: <#list entityDescriptor?keys as key>
 ${key}
</#list>